# Trying to read xml file with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to get the variable whitch is an integer, but it gives me a string.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var test = xmlDoc.Descendants("Variables").Elements("nom").Select(e => (int)e);
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Variables><Site>Chand</Site><nom>12</nom></Variables>
```

Comment: That's an `IEnumerable<int>`, not a string.

Comment: Append a `.First()` and it will be an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you entered is of type `IEnumerable<int>` and not a single int. Try appending `.First()` to get the first (and in this case only) element of the enumerable.

```
var test = xmlDoc.Descendants("Variables").Elements("nom").Select(e => (int)e).First();
```

Comment: yes thanks, do you have some tutorials to learn this things ??

Comment: Just search for XML to LINQ on your favorite search engine and you should find many pages, tutorials and examples, or turn to the book store and get a good book on C# and LINQ in general.

Comment: please how can I get a string for this expression ?

Comment: I mean :
string test = xmlDoc.Descendants("Variables").Elements("nom").Select(e => (string)e).First(); ???